# @font-face use a local fallback if link fails?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I've been trying to find any information on if the way I have currently implemented my font location fallback is correct. Currenty, in my CSS decalaration I do something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src:  local('Open Sans SemiBold'), 
        local('OpenSans-SemiBold'), 
        url('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'), 
        url('//someserver.com/OpenSans-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

will this work? Is my placement correct? Are there any gotchas?

Comment: First of all, "will it work?" is a bit of a silly question. You are currently sitting behind your computer, obviously, so you can simply test for yourself instead of asking here! Then again, only woff2? Ehm, what about people who are slow to upgrade their browsers?

Comment: haha, I was more curious about any gotchas and if this is even the correct way to do it? Also, it's in a limited audience housed from our container application, so we know that it wont need more font support etc.

Comment: To be fair, every version of Edge (august  2016), Firefox (july 2015), and Chrome (july 2014) support WOFF2, so during dev it's pretty reasonable. For prod, all you need to add is the older WOFF format. In comment on the actual question: "just try it and find out" is pretty solid advice, with the caveat that if you're using `@font-face`, checking `local()` means your users are potentially going to use a *completely different version* of the font. Typically you rely on the fact that if people can load a CSS file from your server, they can load your fonts, too.